# Playing audio with audioplayers package from local in flutter web throws `UnimplementedError`

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player, uint8list

I am using [`audioplayers: ^4.0.1`](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) to play audio from the local and url in my flutter application. To pick the file from local I am using the [`file_picker: ^5.2.10`](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker). To play the audio from local I am using the `BytesSource()`. Its working fine in the android but throw the below error in web. What I am doing wrong?

**Error:**

```
Error: UnimplementedError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
packages/audioplayers_web/audioplayers_web.dart 118:5                         setSourceBytes
packages/audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart 318:22                             setSourceBytes
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 430:9                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

**Code:**

```
Future<void> updatingAudio() async {
    audioFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      withData: true,
      type: FileType.audio,
      allowCompression: true,
    );
    if (audioFile != null) {
      audioPlayer.setSource(BytesSource(audioFile!.files.first.bytes!));
    }
    update();
  }
```

Comment: setSourceBytes is not implemented for web https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/packages/audioplayers_web/lib/audioplayers_web.dart#L118

Following their getting started guide, maybe you can use DeviceFileSource instead of BytesSource https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md

Comment: `DeviceFileSource` is only taking File path as its argument. In web getting a file path is not possible. How do I play the local audio file in web. @Wh1t3rabbit

Comment: @SenthurKumaran
i tried out and successfully played a mp3 file locally on chrome like this:
"audioPlayer.play(DeviceFileSource('assets/audios/goal_robot.mp3'));"
assets folder under the root folder and importing the mp3 file in pubspec.yaml. hope it helps

Comment: @Stan I want to play the audio file from the local storage not from the asset folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked perfectly fine with playing the audio from the local storage in the web. By using the [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) package.

**Custom Class:**

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final List<int> bytes;
  final String type;
  MyCustomSource({required this.bytes, required this.type});

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: type,
    );
  }
}
```

**Picking Local File**

```
Future<void> selectingAudio() async {
    audioFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      withData: true,
      type: FileType.audio,
      allowCompression: true,
    );
    if (audioFile != null) {
      try {
        String mimetype = "audio/";
        if (audioFile!.files.first.extension != null) {
          mimetype = mimetype + audioFile!.files.first.extension!;
        } else {
          mimetype = "${mimetype}mp3";
        }
        await audioPlayer
            .setAudioSource(MyCustomSource(bytes: audioFile!.files.first.bytes as List<int>, type: mimetype));
        await audioPlayer.load();
        Duration? duration = await audioPlayer.durationFuture;
        duration ??= Duration.zero;
        if (isPlaying) {
          audioPlayer.stop();
          isPlaying = false;
        }
        audioStartTime = "00:00";
        audioEndTime =
            "${duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}:${duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}";
      } catch (exception, stacktree) {
        debugPrint("$exception");
        debugPrint("$stacktree");
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Wh1t3rabbit `setSourceBytes` is not implemented on multiple platforms. A work around for web was posted in this thread: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1269#issuecomment-1434089114

**Example:**

```
UrlSource urlSourceFromBytes(Uint8List bytes,{String mimeType= "audio/mpeg"}) {
  return  UrlSource(Uri.dataFromBytes(bytes, mimeType: mimeType).toString());
}
Future<void> updatingAudio() async {
    audioFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      withData: true,
      type: FileType.audio,
      allowCompression: true,
    );
    if (audioFile != null) {
      audioPlayer.setSource(urlSourceFromBytes(audioFile!.files.first.bytes!));
    }
   update();
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, it made my code work. I was recording an audio and playing it after, then i encountered the same error as this one.
Thank you